# libGL error: DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1' vs '23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2')

Tags: 22.04, opengl, mesa

I have this error both if I open RVIZ2 or glxinfo moreover if I try to open a video, it says that I don't have the driver.

Here the complete error.

> [rviz2-6] libGL error: DRI driver not from this Mesa build ('23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1' vs '23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2')
> [rviz2-6] libGL error: failed to load driver: iris

If I do `apt list -i | grep mesa` this is the output:

```
libegl-mesa0/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64 [installato] 
libegl1-mesa-dev/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64 [installato, automatico] 
libgl1-mesa-dev/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64 [installato, automatico] 
libgl1-mesa-dri/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64 [installato]
libglapi-mesa/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64 [installato] 
libglu1-mesa-dev/jammy,now 9.0.2-1 amd64 [installato, automatico] 
libglu1-mesa/jammy,now 9.0.2-1 amd64 [installato, automatico] 
libglx-mesa0/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64 [installato] 
mesa-utils-bin/jammy,now 8.4.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installato, automatico] 
mesa-utils/jammy,now 8.4.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installato, automatico] 
mesa-va-drivers/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64 [installato] 
mesa-vdpau-drivers/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64 [installato] 
mesa-vulkan-drivers/jammy-updates,now 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 amd64 [installato]
```

Platform: dell xps 13 plus - ubuntu 22.04.4

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was blocking for me (white screen at startup). I open a bug issue [there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/2054827)
I was able to partially address the issue by making a force downgrade to previous versions of packages, but it is not satisfactory (broken dependencies).

Comment: After trying basically everything that I found online, I discovered that the issue was given by the terminal (I'm used to use Konsole) switching to the integrated terminal everything looked like to working as normal.  By the way thanks for the answer.

Comment: glad you had a solution. Unfortunately, mine was more severe: impossible to start any sessions